# Configure javascript code coverage with sonar

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, sonarqube

How to configure sonar for my javascript project. I want to know about the code coverage and am using ant. Sonar version 2.13 & javascript plugin of version 1.0. 
And this is my build.xml

```
<taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
<classpath path="${lib.dir}/sonar/sonar-ant-task-1.3.jar"/>
</taskdef>

<property name="sonar.jdbc.url"
      value="jdbc:mysql://xxx:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8"/>
<property name="sonar.jdbc.driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/> 
<property name="sonar.jdbc.username" value="sonar"/>
<property name="sonar.jdbc.password" value="sonar"/>

<property name="sonar.host.url" value="xxx"/>

<target name="sonar">
<property name="sonar.sources" value="$${webdir}"/>

<property name="sonar.projectName" value="Project Name"/>
<property name="sonar.language" value="js"/>
<property name="sonar.tests" value="${test.dir}"/>

<sonar:sonar key="org.gap.commerce:services" version="0.1"xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant"/>       
</target>
```

But i didnt get any analysis results. Does anybody know what is wrong in the configuration.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what u tried ? post your code.